# Find index of a given number in a string and avoid numbers within numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get the first match index of a given number in a string in python.

if we have an example such as

```
number = '0.0'
string = '20.0 Rs0.0'
```

and we do

```
string.find(number)
```

my expected answer will be 7, which is the starting index of 0.0 not contained within another number. But obviously here the answer will be 1, which matches 0.0 in 20.0.

Is there a solution using regex/any other method in python which does this ?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: For this use case would it perhaps make more sense to `.split()` the string and operate on that list instead?

Comment: no this should match any string and get the first match of the number, .split() will not be suitable

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

number = '0.0'
string = '20.0 0.0'
print(re.search(fr"\b{re.escape(number)}\b", string).span())
# --> (5, 8)
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear example, I have changed my example a bit. What if characters are there before the number ? It should still match

Comment: ++ @NikhilMishra: Word boundaries should still work. If it doesn't work then please update with more examples

Comment: @NikhilMishra `re.search(fr"\b[A-Za-z]*{re.escape(number)}\b", string).span()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

a_list = ['20.0 0.0', '20.0 Rs0.0', '20.0 Rs0.02', '0.0', '0.02']

r = re.compile(fr'\b0\.0\b|(?<=\D)0\.0(?=\D|$)')
result = []

for n, i in enumerate(a_list):
    if (found := (r.search(i))):
        result.append((n, found.span()))

#[(0, (5, 8)), (1, (7, 10)), (3, (0, 3))]
print(result)
```